# Cypher query produces incomplete results (neo4j-1.9-SNAPSHOT)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have run into the problem when executing a cypher query against a database "neo4j-1.9-SNAPSHOT" on Windows 7.
The database can be downloaded from the topic in [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru&fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/jKt9r2q4ZAk).

When I run the fist 2 queries in the web admin console, I do not get node with id ="45" as the first node in the path in the result list.

```
1) start a = node:my_nodes(label='2826'), b = node:my_nodes(label='2826')
match a-[r1]-b
with a, b, r1
match b-[r2]-c
where c.label = 2826 and r1.label = r2.label and id(r1) <> id(r2)
return id(a), id(b), id(c), id(r1), id(r2); 

2) START n0=node:my_nodes(label='2826'), n1=node:my_nodes(label='2826'), 
      n2=node:my_nodes(label='2826')
MATCH n0-[r0]-n1-[r1]-n2
where r0.label = r1.label and id(r0)<>id(r1) 
RETURN id(n0), id(n1), id(n2), id(r0), id(r1);
```

However, when I run the 3rd query, node with id="45" should definitely be in the result list of the first two queries. Moreover, when checking the database it seems to be the case.

```
3) start a = node(45), b = node:my_nodes(label='2826')
match a-[r1]-b
with a, b, r1
match b-[r2]-c
where a.label = 2826 and c.label = 2826 and r1.label = r2.label and id(r1) <> id(r2)
return id(a), a.label, id(b), id(c), id(r1), id(r2);
```

On running the cypher query:

```
start a = node:my_nodes(label='2826')
return id(a);
```

node with id="45" is in the index.

Any ideas what can be wrong with the first 2 queries?

Comment: just to clarify the problem: you see the node(45) in first two queries but you don't get it using the 3th?

Comment: also please what do you get when you run this query: `start a = node:my_nodes(label='2826') return count(a)`

Comment: it's vice versa: the first two queries do not give me the node with id=45 as a match for `a` while the 3rd definitely shows that there is a match starting from `a`. Thus, the more general (I mean the first two) do not produce the full list of possible matches. as for the `count` query, it returns `33`.